# Classification based on frequency decomposition of timeseries

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, neural-networks, classification, feature-engineering

I'm working on a classification problem where the dataset comprises a quote-unquote frequency profile from a timeseries. My dataset looks like this:

```
sensor1, [(freq1, power1), ... (freqN, powerN)], class
...
sensorM, [(freq1, power1), ... (freqN, powerN)], class
```

where each (freqN, powerN) represents the frequency band and its power as estimated by FFT for a particular sensor. The list [(freq1, pow1), ... (freqN, powN)] for 2 different observations not necessarily include the same frequencies.

I have 2 questions:

1. is the aforementioned dataset equivalent to the following dataset?

```
sensor1, freq1, power1, class
sensor1, freq2, power2, class
...
sensor1, freqN, powerN, class
...
sensorM, freqN, powerN, class
```

2. In case it's not, how would you approach to build a model with such dataset?

Thanks!